# 2008 Audi A6 - How to play music via smartphone?

Tags: audio, audi, bluetooth

**Is there a way to play music from your smartphone in an `Audi A6` from 2008?**

I am looking for anything, such as devices or other gadgets, that may make this possible. I have looked all over the web for a solution to this.

Comment: Do you have an aux-input in the car or for some odd reason is there a tape player?

Comment: Also, try searching for 'Adding A2DP to your audi'. It'll give you tons of results for hardware/guides. (I Don't want to post a specific link to a website just in case :x )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if you'd like a cheap, but functional solution you could buy a so called FM-Transmitter.

These are usually fairly cheap: 10$ / 10€, and aren't too bad.

Depending on the brand, you can connect your AUX cable, SD Card and some may even have bluetooth.

Otherwise you could buy a 'converter' (A2DP for Bluetooth) from your Audi dealer ( or usually other certified shops), that you can connect to your CD Changer/Navigation. You can then connect your aux cable to that.

However, the second option is more expensive (I believe around 60€, and depending on model/year/connection port it can get more expensive) and has to be installed. The first option is simply 'plug and play'.

[image]

Comment: While this is possible, it's a lousy option in my experience. Every 50 km or so you have to change the transmitter frequency as other (much stronger) FM transmitters come into range and start interfering with your 'broadcast'. Audio quality is pretty bad, too.

Comment: @Hobbes I currently have a (more expensive) FM Transmitter. Roughly 25 euro. Still cheaper than the 180 I'd have to pay for the A2DP bluetooth kit thingy. I do agree that if you travel a lot, you'll have to switch frequencies and the audio quality isn't as great. However, I only travel 15km for my work and the frequency I've got is completely empty. Because of that; the audio quality isn't as bad after all. If you do have to travel a lot, I'd suggest the former. If you care less about audio quality, don't want to spend as much or don't travel as much; go for the FM Transmitter. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can play music using your smartphone. You can use a BT adapter. I use WMA3000A I got from viseeousa.com. I plug it directly to my car's AMI port. This both supports iPhone and android. You will be able to stream music via bluetooth and the sound quality is great.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this Bovee WMA 3000A that comes with AMI cable, the best bluetooth adapter in streaming music to iPod ready cars, it supports Android and iPhone which also have steering wheel controls and automatic call switching. Try this, it can solve your problem.

Comment: This answer has already been given, with exactly the same product. Feel free to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Audi sound systems like BNS 5 and RNS-E have a line input. This is part of the [Quadlock](http://pinoutguide.com/Car-Stereo-Audi/audi_rns_pinout.shtml) connector on the back of the unit.

You can get [Aux in adapters](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/AUX-IN-Adapter-fur-Audi-Symphony-Chorus-Concert-3-RNS-E-BNS-5-0-GPS-Radio-iPhone-/262152352711?clk_rvr_id=1301760291751) that plug into this connector. The standard ones provide a 3.5 mm jack, others also provide an iPhone connector.

[This PDF](http://audienthusiasts.com/Downloads/audi_infotainment_Guide.pdf) can help you identify which system is installed in your car.